# Expanding button to autosuggestbox in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am trying to configure a button within my UWP app to expand in to an AutoSuggestBox on click. This behavior is mentioned in this post:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/search#Implementation

I tried utilizing a flyout on the button click, but it doesn't give me the desired effect. Is there an existing control that can do this or will I need to roll my own XAML of an existing control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you see in the blogpost can be easily achieved by having an autosuggestbox hidden behind the button, then after on button click fading out the button and resizing the autosuggestbox to the desired width.

There's no way to "expand" a control into a different one, but you can make it look like that happens :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up using a flyout on the button with a "Left" placement. I added an event handler to set the width of the button to 0 on the flyout opening and then to expand back to its normal width and fade in when the flyout closes.